# How does traverse inorder print values?

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, traversal, inorder

```
class node:
def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val 
        self.left = None 
        self.right = None 
        
class Tree:
    def create(self,data):
        return node(data) 
        
    def insert(self,node,data):
        
        if node is None:
            return self.create(data)
        
        if data < node.data:
            node.left = self.insert(node.left, data) 
            
        else:
            node.right = self.insert(node.right, data)
            
        return node
        
    def search(self,node,data):
        if data == node.data or node is None:
            return node
            
        if node.data < data:
            return self.search(node.right, data)
        else:
            return self.search(node.left, data)
   [ <---       
    def traverseinorder(self,root):
        
        if root is not None:
            print(root.data)
            self.traverseinorder(root.left)
            self.traverseinorder(root.right)
                                       --->]
        
def main():
    root = None
    tree = Tree()
    root = tree.insert(root, 10)
    print(root)
    tree.insert(root, 20)
    tree.insert(root, 30)
    tree.insert(root, 40)
    tree.insert(root, 70)
    tree.insert(root, 60)
    tree.insert(root, 80)

    print("Traverse Inorder")
    tree.traverseinorder(root)
```

I am new to data structures in python.
I don't understand the traverseinorder part. I print only thr root node data, but I didnt use either of print or return statements in self.traverseinorder(root.left) and self.traverseinorder(root.right) but the value is printed. How it is done ?
can anyone explain it in simple english please?

Comment: `print(root.data)` is there and what is `root` after e.g. the fourth recursive step? It is no longer the original root of the tree but some nested node!

Comment: `traverseinorder` prints `root.data`. Then it is called with `root=root.left`, prints the data of that node, and so on.

Comment: Did you use a debugger and step through the code, line by line, inspecting the variables? It would certainly help...